How can I create dynamic metadata for a user profile page in nextjs 15 when using use client
I'm new to nextjs and trying convert a MERN app to nextjs 15.  I'm using the same backend api for I used for the MERN app.
I am trying to generate dynamic metadata in a nextjs 15 app in a user profile page that is using "use client".
My basic /[username] page is:
"use client";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useAppSelector } from "../redux";
import { useGetProfileByUsernameQuery } from "@/state/api";

const ProfilePage = () => {
  const { username } = useParams();
  const userInfo = useAppSelector((state) => state.global.userInfo);

  const isMyProfile = userInfo && userInfo?.data?.username === username;

  const user = useGetProfileByUsernameQuery(username);

  const profile = user.status === "fulfilled" ? user.data[0] : "";
  return (
    <div>
      {user.status === "pending" ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      ) : (
        <h1>{`${profile.firstName} ${profile.lastName}`}</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;

I tried using the generateMetadata function below:
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  return {
    title: `${params.username}'s profile`,
  };
}

When I add this I get the error
You are attempting to export "generateMetadata" from a component marked with "use client", which is disallowed. Either remove the export, or the "use client" directive.

If I remove the "use client" statement, I can't get the user's profile.  I get an error from redux.js saying:
You're importing a component that needs `useRef`


You can refer to this doc

Both static and dynamic metadata through generateMetadata are only supported in Server Components.

In your case
ProfilePage.js
"use client";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useAppSelector } from "../redux";
import { useGetProfileByUsernameQuery } from "@/state/api";

const ProfilePage = () => {
  const { username } = useParams();
  const userInfo = useAppSelector((state) => state.global.userInfo);

  const isMyProfile = userInfo && userInfo?.data?.username === username;

  const user = useGetProfileByUsernameQuery(username);

  const profile = user.status === "fulfilled" ? user.data[0] : "";
  return (
    <div>
      {user.status === "pending" ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      ) : (
        <h1>{`${profile.firstName} ${profile.lastName}`}</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;

username/page.js
import ProfilePage from './ProfilePage';

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  return {
    title: `${params.username}'s profile`,
  };
}

export default Page(){
 return <div><ProfilePage/></div>
}


Just put ,  and metadata  tags anywhere in your component tree, including inside client components. React will automatically detect this and put those tags in  for you.

In profile page add title tag.
"use client";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useAppSelector } from "../redux";
import { useGetProfileByUsernameQuery } from "@/state/api";

const ProfilePage = () => {
  const { username } = useParams();
  const userInfo = useAppSelector((state) => state.global.userInfo);

  const isMyProfile = userInfo && userInfo?.data?.username === username;

  const user = useGetProfileByUsernameQuery(username);

  const profile = user.status === "fulfilled" ? user.data[0] : "";
  return (
    <div>
<title>{`${profile.firstName} ${profile.lastName}`}</title/>
      {user.status === "pending" ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      ) : (
        <h1>{`${profile.firstName} ${profile.lastName}`}</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;

https://nextjs-faq.com/metadata-client-components#how-do-i-set-dynamic-metadata-that-depends-on-client-side-states

Thank you, that worked but is is possible to pass the user's profile data to the generaeMetatata function?  I woul dlike to have the title as "Stephen Moore's" Profile.

What is the source for the user profile? is it API or browser session

I'm getting it from state and the api, const userInfo = useAppSelector((state) => state.global.userInfo); is created on login but to get the full profile I'm getting it from the api call const user = useGetProfileByUsernameQuery(username).  I could use either for the meta data.  The both have the first and last name.

are you using any auth libraray or can you add the useGetProfileByUsernameQuery code

I'm not, it's all done on the backend.  I was initially trying to use auth.js but couldn't figure out how to get it working with the remote api, so I used what I had been using in the mern app.

do you have a backend API to get the user data

I do.  I have a client folder with nextjs for the frontend and a server folder running an express server for the backend.

update the answer

That did it.  Thank you so much.  I just fetch the user profile directly inside the generateMetadata function.  Thank you so much!
